# How to determine whether a geometry is multi-part?

Tags: arcobjects

The title basically says it all. In my case, I have a polyline and I have to find out if it is multi-part or single-part.

In general, the entire Internet (searched via Google), and ESRI's online material in particular, has proven rather neutral on this topic. There was some hope [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/900/arcgisexplorer/sdk/doc/761c0d85-de48-46fe-861c-e685f3a2e046.htm#Multipart%20geometries). The relevant extract copied below:

> You can determine the number of paths in a Polyline or rings in a
>   Polygon by using the PathCount or RingCount properties respectively.
>   Use the overloaded GetPoint methods to get a copy of the Point at a
>   specific position in a specific path or ring. The following code
>   example iterates through all of the points in a Polyline,
>   multiPathLine, using the PathCount, PointCount and GetPoint members:
>
> ```cs
> // Iterate through all points in all paths.
> for (int i = 0; i < multiPathLine.PathCount; i++)
> {
>     for (int j = 0; j < multiPathLine.PointCount(i); j++)
>     {
>         multiPathLine.GetPoint(i, j);
>     }
> }
> ```

Promising as that looked, nowhere on that long, long page do they inform the would-be developer of what type `multiPathLine` is. So I went searching for the elusive `PathCount` property but it remained unfound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is actually so easy: Just cast your polyline to a `IGeometryCollection` and check its `GeometryCount` property. If it is greater than 1, then it is a multi-part geometry.

This works not only with polylines, but with polygons and points, too.

```cs
static bool IsMultiPart(this IGeometry geometry)
{
    var geometryCollection = geometry as IGeometryCollection;
    return geometryCollection != null && geometryCollection.GeometryCount > 1;
}
```